# Signing certificate by self signed CA

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, mosquitto, paho

I have created selfsigned CA certificate on Ubuntu that runs on AWS . I have also created client and server certificates signed by current CA.

SSL connection is used by Mosquitto MQTT service. Unfortunatly I have `Received fatal alert: unknown_ca` error from client side when it tries to connect to server.

I was tested the same certificate generation procedure on my Raspberry Pi and SSL+MQTT works well.

Creating certificates:

```
# CA 
    openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/cakey.pem -out careq.pem -config ./openssl.cnf
    openssl ca -create_serial -out cacert.pem -days 365 -keyfile private/cakey.pem -selfsign -config ./openssl.cnf -infiles careq.pem
# Server 
    openssl req -new -out server.csr -config openssl.cnf  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key
    openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in server.csr -out server.crt
# Client
    openssl req -new -out client.csr -config openssl.cnf  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client.key
    openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in client.csr -out client.crt
```

`openssl.cnf` content:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default            # The default ca section

[ CA_default ]

dir             = .                     # Where everything is kept
certs           = $dir/certsdb          # Where the issued certs are kept
new_certs_dir   = $certs                # default place for new certs.
database        = $dir/index.txt        # database index file.
certificate     = $dir/cacert.pem       # The CA certificate
private_key     = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
serial          = $dir/serial           # The current serial number
RANDFILE        = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file

crldir          = $dir/crl
crlnumber       = $dir/crlnumber        # the current crl number
crl             = $crldir/crl.pem       # The current CRL

x509_extensions = usr_cert              # The extentions to add to the cert

copy_extensions = copy

name_opt        = ca_default            # Subject Name options
cert_opt        = ca_default            # Certificate field options

default_days    = 365                   # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30                    # how long before next CRL
default_md      = sha1                  # which md to use.
preserve        = no                    # keep passed DN ordering

policy          = policy_match

[ policy_match ]
countryName             = match         # Must be the same as the CA
stateOrProvinceName     = match         # Must be the same as the CA
organizationName        = match         # Must be the same as the CA
organizationalUnitName  = optional      # not required
commonName              = supplied      # must be there, whatever it is
emailAddress            = optional      # not required

countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
prompt = yes
default_bits            = 2048
#default_keyfile         = privkey.pem
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name # where to get DN for reqs
attributes              = req_attributes         # req attributes
x509_extensions     = v3_ca  # The extentions to add to self signed certs
req_extensions      = v3_req # The extensions to add to req's

string_mask = nombstr


[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default             = US
countryName_min                 = 2
countryName_max                 = 2

stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default     = California

localityName                    = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default            = Hawthorne

0.organizationName              = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default      = PhilNet

organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default  = UN

commonName                      = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_default              = CN
commonName_max                  = 64

emailAddress_default            = aaa@bbb.cc
emailAddress                    = Email Address
emailAddress_max                = 64

[ req_attributes ]


[ usr_cert ]

basicConstraints=CA:false
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
#subjectAltName=email:move
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1   = 34.245.0.160
DNS.1   = ec2-34-245-0-160.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

[ usr_cert_has_san ]
basicConstraints = CA:false
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer

[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName=email:move

[ v3_ca ]

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
basicConstraints = CA:true

[ v3_ca_has_san ]
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
basicConstraints = CA:true
```

My Java web client uses `paho` library for MQTT communication:

```
public class TestMQTT4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting");

        String serverUrl ="ssl://ec2-34-245-0-160.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8887";
        String path= "C:\\projects\\certs\\U\\CA6\\";


        String caFilePath =path+"cacert.pem";
        String clientCrtFilePath = path+ "client.crt";
        String clientKeyFilePath = path+ "client.key";
        String mqttUserName = "b";
        String mqttPassword = "b";

        MqttClient client;
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(serverUrl, "2");
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setUserName(mqttUserName);
            options.setPassword(mqttPassword.toCharArray());

            options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
            options.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
            options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);


            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = getSocketFactory(caFilePath,clientCrtFilePath, clientKeyFilePath, "aaabbb");
            //SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = getSocketFactory3(caFilePath);
            options.setSocketFactory(socketFactory);

            System.out.println("starting connect the server...");
            client.connect(options);
            System.out.println("connected!");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            client.subscribe("aaa",0);
            client.disconnect();
            System.out.println("disconnected!");


        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }




    private static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(final String caCrtFile,
            final String crtFile, final String keyFile, final String password)
            throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // load CA certificate
        X509Certificate caCert = null;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(caCrtFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
        }
        //System.out.println("load CA certificate certificate done :"+caCert);

        // load client certificate
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(crtFile));
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
        }
        //System.out.println("load client certificate done :"+cert);

        // load client private key
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(keyFile));
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();

        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        PrivateKey pk=null;

        if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
            KeyPair key;
            PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(password.toCharArray());
            System.out.println("Encrypted key - we will use provided password");
            key = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object)
                    .decryptKeyPair(decProv));
            pk = key.getPrivate();

        } else 
        if (object instanceof PrivateKeyInfo)
        {
            System.out.println("got PrivateKeyInfo ");
            pk =  converter.getPrivateKey((PrivateKeyInfo) object);
            System.out.println("algorithm "+pk.getAlgorithm() +" format " + pk.getFormat());


        }else
        if (object instanceof PEMKeyPair)
        {
            KeyPair key;
            System.out.println("Unencrypted key - no password needed "+object.getClass().getName());
            key = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
            pk = key.getPrivate();
        }


        pemParser.close();

        // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
        KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        caKs.load(null, null);
        caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", caCert);


        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }

        } };



        // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate
        // us
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("certificate", cert);
        ks.setKeyEntry("private-key", pk, password.toCharArray(),
                new java.security.cert.Certificate[] { cert });
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

        // finally, create SSL socket factory
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }


}
```

Log:

```
...
                                 ....
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
update handshake state: certificate_verify[15]
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
MQTT Con: 2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
update handshake state: change_cipher_spec
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
MQTT Con: 2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 74, 211, 43, 244, 29, 37, 34, 169, 164, 170, 51, 82 }
***
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
MQTT Con: 2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
MQTT Con: 2, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
MQTT Con: 2, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, unknown_ca
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
MQTT Con: 2, called closeSocket()
MQTT Con: 2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
MQTT Con: 2, called close()
MQTT Con: 2, called closeInternal(true)
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

UPD

I found difference in Signature Algorithm in log file in good connection (Raspberry Pi) and bad one (Ubuntu on AWS)

Failed (Ubuntu on AWS)

```
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
```

Good (Raspberry Pi)

```
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
```

Why I have different signature algorithm? In moth cases identical commands was used to create and sign certificates.

Might it be problem while communicating with Java?

**UPD**

I did some changes accoding to comments and now my certificates works fine.

Certificates generation proedure:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/cakey.pem -out careq.pem -config ./openssl.cnf -extensions v3_ca_509 -reqexts v3_ca_req -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Hawthorne/O=PhilNet/CN=CA/"
openssl ca -create_serial -out cacert.pem -days 365 -keyfile private/cakey.pem -selfsign -config ./openssl.cnf  -extensions v3_ca_509 -infiles careq.pem

openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.csr -config openssl.cnf -reqexts v3_server_req -nodes -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Hawthorne/O=PhilNet/CN=Server/"
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in server.csr -out server.crt

openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout client.key -out client.csr -config openssl.cnf -reqexts v3_server_req -nodes -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Hawthorne/O=PhilNet/CN=Client/"
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -in client.csr -out client.crt
```

openssl.cnf file:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default            # The default ca section

[ CA_default ]

dir             = .                     # Where everything is kept
certs           = $dir/certsdb          # Where the issued certs are kept
new_certs_dir   = $certs                # default place for new certs.
database        = $dir/index.txt        # database index file.
certificate     = $dir/cacert.pem       # The CA certificate
private_key     = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
serial          = $dir/serial           # The current serial number
RANDFILE        = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file

crldir          = $dir/crl
crlnumber       = $dir/crlnumber        # the current crl number
crl             = $crldir/crl.pem       # The current CRL

#x509_extensions = usr_cert              # The extentions to add to the cert

copy_extensions = copy

name_opt        = ca_default            # Subject Name options
cert_opt        = ca_default            # Certificate field options

default_days    = 365                   # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30                    # how long before next CRL
default_md      = sha1                  # which md to use.
preserve        = no                    # keep passed DN ordering

policy          = policy_anything

[ policy_anything ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
prompt = yes
default_bits            = 2048
attributes              = req_attributes         
#x509_extensions    = v3_ca  # The extentions to add to self signed certs
#req_extensions     = v3_req # The extensions to add to req's

string_mask = nombstr



[ req_attributes ]


[ v3_ca_509 ]
basicConstraints = CA:true
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

[ v3_ca_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:true
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, keyCertSign


[ v3_server_req ]
basicConstraints=CA:false
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
subjectAltName = @alt_names_server


[alt_names_server]
IP.1   = 34.245.0.159
DNS.1   = ec2-34-245-0-159.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

[ v3_client_req ]
basicConstraints=CA:false
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
subjectAltName = @alt_names_client

[alt_names_client]
IP.1   = 192.168.1.103
DNS.1   = GM
```

Comment: The signature algorithm in 'CertificateVerify' has nothing to do with the signature in the cert, which your log shows is **SHA1** withRSA -- as expected since that's what your `openssl.cnf` says. If you're using the same client in both cases, it might be a difference in the server's `CertificateRequest` -- did you compare those? In any case, all your certs (the apparent server and client and CA certs) all have the default names from your config for both subject and issuer, implying when you ran `req -new` you just accepted the defaults every time. That's wrong ...

Comment: ... server and client must have names (in Subject, which is copied from the CSR) different from the CA. (The _CA_ cert, being a root, does have Issuer==Subject, but the server and client cierts must have Issuer== _CAname_ !=Subject.) The server cert is in fact invalid, but since you used the 'I want to be robbed TrustManager' your client ignored this error; OTOH the server detected your client cert is invalid and that's the cause of the alert you're complaining about. You also have wrong extensions in the CA cert, but I'm not sure offhand if those get checked.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You are right, evrything is working now. Ready to accept your answer. I did message body update with more details