# Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA failed in Java

Tags: java, ssl, paho, pyopenssl, java-security

[I have identically generated and signed certificates in Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880571/signing-certificate-by-self-signed-ca).

SSL connection works fine on Raspberry while fails on Ubuntu with error `Received fatal alert: unknown_ca`

During certificate verify procedure I found difference:

Failed (Ubuntu on AWS)

```
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
```

Good (Raspberry Pi)

```
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
```

Why I have different signature algorithm? In both cases identical commands was used to create and sign certificates.

Might it be problem while communicating with Java?

**UPD**

Trying to enable Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy

I have two folders in my Java installation that contains `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar`:

```
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\security\policy\limited
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\security\policy\unlimited
```

I suppose `unlimited` folder contains required libs, but to be sure I have downloaded them from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and overwritten.

I uncomented line `crypto.policy=unlimited` in `C:\java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\security\java.security` file

But problem remains the same. Is till have error:

```
MQTT Con: 2, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, unknown_ca
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
```

Comment: Which version of Java (and from which "vendor") do you use on both platforms?

Comment: I'm using Mosquitto MQQT on Linux systems and Java 8 from Oracle as client.

Comment: Got the same error with Java 13

Comment: The CertificateVerify algorithm has nothing to do with the cert signature OR the alert (see comment on your original Q) and none of them is affected in any way by the crypto policy.

Answer (score 0):

I would try checking if your client has **Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy** enabled.

- `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security` (for JDK)
- `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security` (for JRE)

The file has to have the line: `crypto.policy=unlimited`

If it's not there you will have to download a distributable from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and then add the above line into the `security` file.

Comment: I found `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file and undocumented required line.  And there is no `security` folder in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/`. I still have the same error after this change

Comment: @vico, if the line was commented out, then uncomenting it has to happen **together with** installing the JAR file from Oracle, from the link I had posted

Comment: You are right, I did required changes, but still have the same error. More details in UPD.

Comment: unlimited policy has been the default since 8u161 in 2017, and more importantly the 'limited' policy _never ever_ applied to hashing or signature.